# How to recognize a gesture like long pressing for a while before pan on IOS?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to recognize a pan gesture by `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. But I want to know if there was a long press before this pan gesture. If not, I will not take this gesture into consider. Please help me.

Comment: see this [Long press gesture recong][1]


  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I can recognize Long Press. But I want to recognize a pan gesture after a long press. My expected UI is a user long press a `UIImageView`, and then can move it.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is sufficient for this. It is continuous so you can also track finger movement after the long press.

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers
>   (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period
>   (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the
>   allowable range of movement (allowableMovement). The gesture
>   recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves,
>   and it ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when any of the fingers
>   are lifted.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer).